# Kestrel server has already started

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis-express, .net-core-3.0, kestrel

When starting the `.net core 3.0.100` application with the `IIS Express`:
[image] I am getting the next error.

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Server has already started.

Also the same error when starting with command line:
`dotnet run -w`

This startup code, that creates hostBuilder and start the application

```
private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                })
                .UseNLog();
        });

public static void Main(string[] args) => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run(); // errors throws here
```

I assume the error means that server has already started :) But I have no idea, when has it been started?

**UPDATE 1**

When investigating IIS log has seen next the lib that threw the exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

**UPDATE 2**

After running `dotnet run` I see a lot of spawned dotnet processes:
[image]

I can kill them all, but when I kill the last one(highlighted with red) it restarts immediatly with another PID. And if I try to `dotnet run` after I have killed as much as I can, still has the same error.

If wait for about 5 minutes, then I can kill even the last process, but still can not `dotnet run`

**UPDATE 3**

Has tried

```
dotnet build-server shutdown
dotnet run
```

Result is the same

**UPDATE 4**

Have tried
`dotnet <build-result-name>.dll`

Still has the same error, but know only one `dotnet.exe` process has been spawned. This process that can be killed in 5 minutes from the **UPDATE 2**

My assumptions, that somehow the kestrel server has started, before `StartAsync` from kestrel, but I am missing when and how.

**UPDATE 5**

Code listing for startup

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "wwwroot";
            });

        services
            .AddLocalizationOptions(Configuration)
            .AddHttpContextAccessor()
            .AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>()
            .AddSecurityAuthentication(
                this.Configuration,
                options => options
                    .UseUserModel<User>()
                    .AddUserService<UserService>()
                    .AddSecurityJwtAuthentication())
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddLogging(builder => builder
                .AddConfiguration(Configuration)
                .AddConsole()
                .AddNLog())
            .AddMvcCore()
            .AddControllersAsServices()
            .AddCustomJsonOptions(this.hostingEnvironment)
            .AddCustomCors();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // If, for some reason, you need a reference to the built container, you
        // can use the convenience extension method GetAutofacRoot.
        this.AutofacContainer = app.ApplicationServices.GetAutofacRoot();

        app
            .UseRequestLocalization(
                RequestLocalizationConfigurator.GetRequestLocalizationOptions(app.ApplicationServices))
            .UseHttpsRedirection()
            .UseMiddleware<SpaRoutingMiddleware>()
            .UseStaticFiles()
            .UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>()
            .UseRouting()
            .UseCors(CorsPolicyName.AllowAny)
            .UseAuthentication()
            .UseAuthorization()
            .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
            });

        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "../../../../client";
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does this issue happen on a new Asp.Net Core MVC template? Check Task Manager to see whether you have already start it.

Comment: @TaoZhou I have updated the question, is it the thing you have mean?

Comment: Just shooting. Have you tried adding to your webbuilder: UseKestrel() and UseIISIntegration() methods? Those maybe just needed for the REAL IIS, not Express, but I don't really know that.

Comment: For me, this was related to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` when trying to migrate to .NET 6 Preview 5.

Comment: @DanielLozano, how did you solve the issue?

Comment: It is a pre-release bug. https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/known-issues.md#net-runtime